# React convert JSON date to relative time

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, datetime, frontend

How do I convert this:

```
2017-08-14T23:28:56.782Z
```

Into relative time e.g. "21d".
If there is an npm dependency I can use that too.

Comment: i would look at using `moment`. That is the main js time library

Comment: You can get a vanilla Javascript `Date` object doing simply `var date = new Date('2017-08-14T23:28:56.782Z');`, but doing the relative time could get messy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using moment.js, you can do `moment("2017-08-14T23:28:56.782Z").fromNow();`. This will give you 21 days ago

```js
console.log(moment("2017-08-14T23:28:56.782Z").fromNow());
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some useful library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) which will easy the way.

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 21 days ago, then [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is convenient for things like that. There is also [react-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime), but I don't have any experience using it with React, so I can't comment on its efficacy or ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Use moment.js.
`npm install moment`

```
moment([2017, 9, 4]).fromNow();
```